# tableview reloaddata in masterview from detail view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

I have a master-detail application that has a tableview in the `masterViewController` and in the `detailview` you can edit and add info into textfields and so on. I have a save button as the `rightBarButtonItem` in the detail view. If they did not save their work and they hit back I have a `UIAlertView` that popsup asking them if they want to save their work. Behind the alertview the detailview is still dismissed and the masterviewcontroller is now showing.

So when I hit save the tableview does not update. I have `[tableview reloadData]` in my masterviewcontroller `viewWillAppear` but it does not work because the viewappears behind the alertview before the user can hit save. I would like to call the `[tableview reloadData]` (or something similar) in this method here which is called from my detailview.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

I can't just call `[tableview reloadData]` because the alertViews delegate is set as the detailview because it is pulling all the information from the textfields to save into the plist if they push save on the alertview. Is there a way I can call `[tableView reloadData]` from my alertView?

Comment: Does the saving fail in both circumstances? i.e. from the `rightBarButtonItem` and from the `alertView`? Also, why are you dismissing the `detailView` before the `alertView` is dismissed?

Comment: no the saving was working for the rightBarButtonItem. the detailView was being dismissed automatically because i'm using a master-detail application template. I got it figured out i wrote my solution below. thanks for your time. unless you know of a way to delay the detailView from being dismissed in the master-detail application template. -cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. What I did was created a property of `UITableViewController` in my DetailViewController.h file and named it masterView then synthesized it in its .m file. I then went into my masterViewController.m file and found the method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`and set my detailsViewController.masterView property to self (self being the masterViewController).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      self.detailViewController.masterView = self;
}
```

I then went into my UIAlertView Save Method and called reloadData on the masterViews tableView

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [masterView.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

This is very much like passing info to an array or dictionary in the detail view from the `tableView indexPath.row` like this below (which is also in the method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`)

```
self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are dismissing the `detailView` before any button is tapped on the `alertView`. I don't know where you save your data and where the `tableView` retrieves it from but try waiting for user interaction on the `alertView`.

In the code where you pop the `alertView` to ask for save, do nothing else.

```
- (void)yourBackButtonAction //i assumed this is your method when they hit 'back'
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Would you like to save your work?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No"  otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

And in the delegate method, save the data and dismiss the `detailView`:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     if (buttonIndex == 1) //yes
    {
        //save your data
        [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else // no
        [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now in your `masterViewController's` `viewWillAppear` method, `[self.tableView reloadData]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

set the property of the `tableview` and try

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

Comment: I can't do self.tableView because the alertViews Delegate is the DetailView so when I call self it thinks I'm calling the detailView not the masterView (where the tableView is located)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to create a delegate method for this.

- Create a protocol,
- Create one method inside for e.g. `- (void) updateMyMasterTable;`
- Create a delegate instance like `id <ProtocolName> obj;` in your detail class & write  in .h file.
- Synthesize it.
- When you want to reload your master's tableview call `[obj updateMyMasterTable];`
- In your master class .m file implement `- (void) updateMyMasterTable` method & call `[tableView reloadData];`